# stuck on a python issue

Tags: python, google-analytics

I'm using the pyga python module to do some Google Analytics reporting server side (instead of ga.js).

PYGA:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyga

Everything works great so far.. but I'm currently having a problem adding "items" to the track_transaction(). It seems to want some type of array or list, I'm not fluent enough in python to break it down.. and any help would be greatly appreciated

I've tried these to no avail:

```
trans.items = {"order_id":"12222","sku":"PP1","name":"Donation","price":"0.44", "quanity":"1"}
```

---

```
trans.items=[ ['order_id', '12222'], ['sku', 'PayPal1'], ['name', 'Donation'], ['price', '0.44'], ['quanity', '1'] ]
```

---

```
trans.items = [12222,'PP1','Donation','0.44',1,1]
```

---

```
gaitems = Item()
gaitems.order_id='12222'
gaitems.sku='PP1'
gaitems.name='Test'
gaitems.price='0.44'
gaitems.quanity='1'
gaitems.variation='1'
trans.items=gaitems


tracker.track_transaction(trans, session, visitor)
```

---

This is what I'm using to instantiate

---

```
tracker = Tracker('UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'domain.com')
        visitor = Visitor()
        visitor.ip_address = '192.168.1.1'
        session = Session()
        page = Page('/index.html')
        tracker.track_pageview(page, session, visitor)

        # Transaction
        trans = Transaction()
        trans.order_id = '001000'
        trans.affiliation = 'paypal'
        trans.total = '0.44'
        trans.tax = '0.00'
        trans.shipping = '0.00'
        trans.city ='NA'
        trans.state ='NA'
        trans.country = 'US'

        tracker.track_transaction(trans, session, visitor)
```

---

Track Transaction Function

---

```
def track_transaction(self, transaction, session, visitor):
    '''Combines _addTrans(), _addItem() (indirectly) and _trackTrans() of GA Javascript client.'''
    transaction.validate()

    params = {
        'config': self.config,
        'tracker': self,
        'visitor': visitor,
        'session': session,
        'transaction': transaction,
    }
    request = TransactionRequest(**params)
    request.fire()

    for item in transaction.items:
        item.validate()

        params = {
            'config': self.config,
            'tracker': self,
            'visitor': visitor,
            'session': session,
            'item': item,
        }
        request = ItemRequest(**params)
        request.fire()
```

---

Transaction Class

---

```
class Transaction(object):
'''
Represents parameters for a Transaction call

Properties:
order_id -- Order ID, will be mapped to "utmtid" parameter
affiliation -- Affiliation, Will be mapped to "utmtst" parameter
total -- Total Cost, will be mapped to "utmtto" parameter
tax -- Tax Cost, will be mapped to "utmttx" parameter
shipping -- Shipping Cost, values as for unit and price, will be mapped to "utmtsp" parameter
city -- Billing City, will be mapped to "utmtci" parameter
state -- Billing Region, will be mapped to "utmtrg" parameter
country -- Billing Country, will be mapped to "utmtco" parameter
items -- @entity.Items in a transaction

'''

def __init__(self):
    self.items = []
    self.order_id = None
    self.affiliation = None
    self.total = None
    self.tax = None
    self.shipping = None
    self.city = None
    self.state = None
    self.country = None

def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name == 'order_id':
        for itm in self.items:
            itm.order_id = value
    object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

def validate(self):
    if len(self.items) == 0:
        raise exceptions.ValidationError('Transaction need to consist of at least one item')

def add_item(self, item):
    ''' item of type entities.Item '''
    if isinstance(item, Item):
        item.order_id = self.order_id
        self.items.append(item)
```

---

Item Class

---

```
class Item(object):
'''
Represents an Item in Transaction

Properties:
order_id -- Order ID, will be mapped to "utmtid" parameter
sku -- Product Code. This is the sku code for a given product, will be mapped to "utmipc" parameter
name -- Product Name, will be mapped to "utmipn" parameter
variation -- Variations on an item, will be mapped to "utmiva" parameter
price -- Unit Price. Value is set to numbers only, will be mapped to "utmipr" parameter
quantity -- Unit Quantity, will be mapped to "utmiqt" parameter

'''

def __init__(self):
    self.order_id = None
    self.sku = None
    self.name = None
    self.variation = None
    self.price = None
    self.quantity = 1

def validate(self):
    if not self.sku:
        raise exceptions.ValidationError('sku/product is a required parameter')
```

Comment: please fix your indentation.

Comment: *"It seems to want some type of array or list"* —can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: In the Transaction class.. it has: 
   **self.items = []*** which is setting it up as an array as far as I can tell? In the track_transaction function it also loops through it **for item in transaction.items:**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest it looks like you should be using `trans.add_item(my_item)` where `my_item` is an instance of `Item` instead of trying to manually assign a list to `trans.items`

Comment: THANK YOU!! I've been working on this for hours lol.. that was it, it worked perfectly!! thank you again!